# Using Deep Neural Networks to perform LASSO regularization on inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, sparse-matrix, lasso-regression

Can someone tell me any suggestions about building Neural Networks in order to perform LASSO regularization on the inputs of the NN? What I'm looking for is a DNN which is able to compute the classic Cost function optimization of LASSO and being able to give me in output the sparse weight vector that I would obtain with LASSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LASSO-regression adds the L1-norm of the weights to the cost function. Encouraging weights to be close to zero (also called sparse).

The same can be done in Neural Networks and is simply called *Weight Regularization*, see [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/weight-regularization-to-reduce-overfitting-of-deep-learning-models/) or [here](https://cedar.buffalo.edu/%7Esrihari/CSE574/Chap5/Chap5.5-Regularization.pdf). In Keras for example you can pass a `regularizer`-object to the constructor of the layer and it will regularize the weights automatically.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

layer = layers.Dense(
    units=64,
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)
)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lasso. You can not force weights of a DNN to zero, while Lasso shrinks the weights to zero. a DNN with L1-norm for layers regularize or penalize weights but never set them to zero.